# checkbox.checked is always false in a grid view in IE

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a checkbox inside a `GridView`. When i click on save button, i check at code behind which check boxes are checked to save the record in dbms. But `Checkbox.checked` property is always `false`.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox chbx = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chk1");
    if (chbx.Checked)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However it works fine in Mozilla but  not in IE.

Comment: Similar question here: is your issue the same? "gridview wasn't inside my form tags"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590804/checkboxes-in-gridview-using-ie

Answer (score -1):

That's very rare that your server side code is working on one browser but not on another, But most common reason of this problem is that you might be binding your `GridView` in `Page_Load` without checking `IsPostback` property,
your code should be like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
            BindYourGridView();// Bind your grid here only during first page load not every time
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the issue across all browsers?

Comment: No I don't think so, Browser issues occur due to java script only, I don't think that this C#( server side code ) will cause any browser issue.